# react-native facebook login correct implementation

Tags: laravel, react-native, facebook-login

I am developing a mobile app which has a traditional email/password authentication system.

I want to add the facebook login feature to the app. However I do not know how to proceed after the sdk returns that the user is successfully logged in through facebook.

What am I supposed to do in terms of database ? (I'm using Laravel + mysql + laravel passport for authentication)

How do I return a token to the user? How is the flow supposed to be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few things to do,

1. The phone number becomes the primary key.
2. Email and other user information not being collected at first step in sign up becomes nullable().
3. You need to return token using JSON response.
4. In Laravel's route/api.php, you need to create an api route.
5. In the controller, write the logic and return a JSON response (either add the token in response body or response header. It's preferred to add it in the response header.)